# Can I implement change tracking on a classes that derive from a wsdl imported classes in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, oop, design-patterns, delphi-2010

Is there a way to implement change tracking in a derived class without overriding the getters and setters of the base class?
I have an entity framework based multi-tier project in development with the data access and business logic eventually moving to C# based server application. (Data access has already been migrated) The client is in Delphi 2010.
I have used data transfer objects for passing information between the client and server, however it was necessary to implement my own change tracking from Delphi. I originally achieved that by inheriting from the Dtos in the wsdl and "overriding" the getters and setters.
Base class in wsdl import (no real control over this):

```
// ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : DtoCONTAINER_JNL, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://k3scs.com/WCF
  // ************************************************************************ //
  DtoCONTAINER_JNL = class(DtoBase)
  private
    FJNL_ID: Integer;
    FJNL_TYPE_ID: Integer;
    FJNL_DATE: TXSDateTime;
 published
    property JNL_ID:      Integer      read FJNL_ID write FJNL_ID;
    property JNL_TYPE_ID: Integer      read FJNL_TYPE_ID write FJNL_TYPE_ID;
    property JNL_DATE:    TXSDateTime  read FJNL_DATE write FJNL_DATE;
```

Derived classes:

```
  TDtoCONTAINER_JNL = class(DtoCONTAINER_JNL, IDto)
  private
    FName             : string;
    FReferenceCounted : boolean;
    _isNew            : boolean;
    FModified         : boolean;
    FJNL_ID           : integer;
    FJNL_TYPE_ID      : integer;
    FJNL_DATE         : TDateTime;
  public
    property JNL_ID : integer read FJNL_ID write SetJNL_ID;
    property JNL_TYPE_ID : integer read FJNL_TYPE_ID write SetJNL_TYPE_ID;
    property JNL_DATE : TDateTime read GetJNL_DATE write SetJNL_DATE;
```

typical setter method:

```
procedure TDtoCONTAINER_JNL.SetJNL_DATE(const value : TDateTime);
begin
  ChangedProperties:= DtoGenerics.ChangeTracker('JNL_DATE', value, inherited JNL_DATE, self.IsLoaded, ChangedProperties);
  inherited JNL_DATE := DtoGenerics.GetXsDate(value);
end;
```

typical getter method:

```
function TDtoCONTAINER_JNL.GetJNL_DATE : TDateTime;
begin
  Result := DtoGenerics.GetDate(inherited JNL_DATE);
end;
```

Whenever a property is set, the change tracker adds this property name to a list of changed properties for return to the server. This allows the update statements to be targeted and efficient. The problem is each of the getters/setters have practically made the derived classes incompatible with the base, that is, polymorphism is broken, and casting no longer works as expected.
The classes above are generated from a t4 template in C# based on the corresponding database tables/entities, so changing the over 100 classes shouldn't be a problem.
Does anyone have any experience with this?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

the Wsdl importer consists mainly of constants that use string format or something similar to create the Delphi equivalent of the complex types. I made the following changes, using similar constant names to easily identify my changes, and also where to place them in relation to pre-existing code.
Ideally, I would get rid of inheritance completely and just use modified versions of my classes in the wsdl, because I still can't submit a modified Tdto even if I cast it back to a Dto class because the web service rejects it with a message like "expecting DtoObject, but got undtoUnit.TdtoObject instead".
So, I make do with inheritance to handle conversions between ArrayOfObjects to TList and vice versa.
Here are the changes, as best as I can remember:

```
// In WSDLImpConst
// I changed sRemoteClassDeclPas constant value of 'private' to 'proctected'
// Then I added these after SUnitInit
sTrackerDec   =     sTrackerProcPrefix+ sTrackerProcArgs                  + sLineBreak;
sTrackerProc  =      sTrackerDec + 'begin'                                + sLineBreak +
        '  Result:= nProps;'                                              + sLineBreak +
        '  if (_loaded) and (oVal <> pVal) then'    + sLineBreak +
        '  begin '                                                        + sLineBreak +
        '    Result := TrackChange(pName, nProps);'                       + sLineBreak +
        '  end;'                                                          + sLineBreak +
        'end;'                                                            + sLineBreak ;


sTracker2Dec  =       sTrackerProcPrefix+ sTracker2ProcArgs               + sLineBreak;
sTracker2Proc  =      sTracker2Dec + 'begin'                              + sLineBreak +
        '  Result:= nProps;'                                              + sLineBreak +
        '  if (_loaded) and (oVal <> DateTimeToXSDateTime(pVal)) then'    + sLineBreak +
        '  begin '                                                        + sLineBreak +
        '    Result := TrackChange(pName, nProps);'                       + sLineBreak +
        '  end;'                                                          + sLineBreak +
        'end;'                                                            + sLineBreak ;

sTracker3Dec  =       sTrackerProcPrefix+ sTracker3ProcArgs               + sLineBreak;
sTracker3Proc  =      sTracker3Dec + 'begin'                              + sLineBreak +
        '  Result:= nProps;'                                              + sLineBreak +
        '    if nProps = '''' then'                                       + sLineBreak +
        '      nProps := pName'                                           + sLineBreak +
        '    else'                                                        + sLineBreak +
        '      nProps := pName + '','' + nProps;'                         + sLineBreak +
        '  Result:= nProps;'                                              + sLineBreak +
        'end;'                                                            + sLineBreak ;
sTracker4Dec  =       sTrackerProcPrefix+ sTracker4ProcArgs               + sLineBreak;
sTracker4Proc  =      sTracker4Dec + 'begin'                              + sLineBreak +
        '  Result:= nProps;'                                              + sLineBreak +
        '  if (_loaded) and (oVal <> pVal) then'                          + sLineBreak +
        '  begin '                                                        + sLineBreak +
        '    Result := TrackChange(pName, nProps);'                       + sLineBreak +
        '  end;'                                                          + sLineBreak +
        'end;'

//Added my own setters:
sRemoteClassSetterImplPas = 'procedure %0:s.Set%1:s(const A%2:s: %2:s);'  + sLineBreak +
              'begin'                                                     + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s := A%2:s;'                                         + sLineBreak +
              'end;'                                                      + sLineBreak;

sRemoteClassSetterImplPas2= 'procedure %0:s.Set%1:s(const A%2:s: %2:s);'  + sLineBreak +
              'begin'                                                     + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s := A%2:s;'                                         + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s_Specified := True;'                                + sLineBreak +
              'end;'                                                      + sLineBreak;

sRemoteClassSetterImplPas3 = 'procedure %0:s.Set%1:s(const A%2:s: %2:s);' + sLineBreak +
              'begin'                                                     + sLineBreak +
              '  ChangedProperties:= TrackChange(''%1:s'', A%2:s, F%1:s, self.IsLoaded, ChangedProperties);' + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s := A%2:s;'                             + sLineBreak +
              'end;'                                          + sLineBreak;

sRemoteClassSetterImplPas4 = 'procedure %0:s.Set%1:s(const A%2:s: %2:s);'    + sLineBreak +
              'begin'                                         + sLineBreak +
              '  ChangedProperties:= TrackChange(A%2:s, F%1:s, ''%1:s'', self.IsLoaded, ChangedProperties);' + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s := A%2:s;'                             + sLineBreak +
              'end;'                                          + sLineBreak;
// And for indexed properties
sRemoteClassSetterImplPasIdx2=
              'procedure %0:s.Set%1:s(Index: Integer; const A%2:s: %2:s);'    + sLineBreak +
              'begin'                                         + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s := A%2:s;'                             + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s_Specified := True;'                    + sLineBreak +
              'end;'                                          + sLineBreak;

sRemoteClassSetterImplPasIdx3 =
              'procedure %0:s.Set%1:s(Index: Integer; const A%2:s: %2:s);'    + sLineBreak +
              'begin'                                         + sLineBreak +
              '  ChangedProperties:= TrackChange(''%1:s'', A%2:s, F%1:s, self.IsLoaded, ChangedProperties);' + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s := A%2:s;'                             + sLineBreak +
              'end;'                                          + sLineBreak;

sRemoteClassSetterImplPasIdx4 =
              'procedure %0:s.Set%1:s(Index: Integer; const A%2:s: %2:s);'    + sLineBreak +
              'begin'                                         + sLineBreak +
              '  ChangedProperties:= TrackChange(A%2:s, F%1:s, ''%1:s'', self.IsLoaded, ChangedProperties);' + sLineBreak +
              '  F%1:s := A%2:s;'                             + sLineBreak +
              'end;'                                          + sLineBreak;

// Added these before the SImplDecl constant:
sIntfFactoryDecl   = '_di_%0:s Get%0:s(bool useWSDL=false, AnsiString addr="", THTTPRIO* HTTPRIO=0);' + sLineBreak + sLineBreak;
sTrackerProcPrefix =  'function TrackChange';
sTrackerProcArgs =  '(const pName: string; pVal, oVal: variant; _loaded: boolean; nProps: string): string; overload';
sTracker2ProcArgs = '(const pName: string; pVal: TDateTime; oVal: txsdateTime; _loaded:boolean; nProps: string): string; overload;';
sTracker3ProcArgs = '(const pName: string; nProps: string): string; overload;';
sTracker4ProcArgs = '(pVal, oVal: TByteDynArray; const pName: string; _loaded: boolean; nProps: string): string; overload';
sIntfTrackDecl   = sTrackerProcPrefix + sTrackerProcArgs+ sLineBreak;
sIntfTrack2Decl   = sTrackerProcPrefix + sTracker2ProcArgs+ sLineBreak;
sIntfTrack3Decl   = sTrackerProcPrefix + sTracker3ProcArgs+ sLineBreak;
sIntfTrack4Decl   = sTrackerProcPrefix + sTracker4ProcArgs+ sLineBreak;

// Then in WSDLPasWriter I added my new constant arrays:

SetterImpl2:array[Boolean] of string = (sRemoteClassSetterImplPas2, sRemoteClassSetterImplPasIdx2);
SetterImpl3:array[Boolean] of string = (sRemoteClassSetterImplPas3, sRemoteClassSetterImplPasIdx3);
SetterImpl4:array[Boolean] of string = (sRemoteClassSetterImplPas4, sRemoteClassSetterImplPasIdx4);

// then modified the setter section in 'WriteComplexTypeClass'
{ Setter }
if UseSetGets or GenSpecifiedSupport(Member) then
begin
if GenSpecifiedSupport(Member) then
begin
  WriteFmt(SetterImpl2[HasIndexDecl(Member)],[WSDLType.LangName,
                                        Member.LangName,
                                        Member.DataType.LangName])
end
else
begin
  if (ContainsStr(BaseName, 'Dto')) and (not ContainsStr(Member.DataType.LangName, 'XS'))
  and (not ContainsStr(Member.DataType.LangName, 'ArrayOf')) then
    if (ContainsStr(Member.DataType.LangName, 'TByteDynArray')) then
      WriteFmt(SetterImpl4[HasIndexDecl(Member)],[WSDLType.LangName,
                                              Member.LangName,
                                              Member.DataType.LangName])
    else
      WriteFmt(SetterImpl3[HasIndexDecl(Member)],[WSDLType.LangName,
                                              Member.LangName,
                                              Member.DataType.LangName])

  else
    WriteFmt(SetterImpl1[HasIndexDecl(Member)],[WSDLType.LangName,
                                            Member.LangName,
                                            Member.DataType.LangName]);

end;

// at WriteInterfaceEnd I added

WriteFmt(sIntfTrackDecl, []);
WriteFmt(sIntfTrack2Decl, []);
WriteFmt(sIntfTrack3Decl, []);
WriteFmt(sIntfTrack4Decl, []);

// at WriteInterfaceBegin I added
WriteLn(sTrackerProc, []);
WriteLn(sTracker2Proc, []);
WriteLn(sTracker3Proc, []);
WriteLn(sTracker4Proc, []);
// finally I changed the wsdlImp dpr and replaced 'AnsiString' (or 'widestring' I can't remember) with 'string'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the WSDL to Delphi converter sourcecode is part of Delphi enterprise and higher (it is called `WSDLImp.dpr` in the `wsdlimporter` directory).

I'd adapt that to generate your own classes directly.

Comment: That's a fantastic idea, never even crossed my mind. I'll look into that

Comment: You are most welcome (: Let me know how well it goes. In fact, I'd be very much interested in how well the current one can be adapted, as the new languages features (generics, attributes) could warrant a much better generation of wrapper code.

Comment: I've done it. I found it too complicated for now, so I made one simple change to sRemoteClassDeclPas (private to protected in wsdlImpConst), so I can access all the fields and methods from the derived class. So I simply override the Setters sure that the fields will all be visible from the derived class. I might try out further changes if required, but this is an epic change. Thanks!

Comment: The WsdlImp source that came with delphi 2010, is older than the wsdlimp.exe that came with Delphi 2010, so strings are being converted to ansistrings, so I've just changed that, but it would be useful to get the matching source for the wsdlimp.exe they ship with 2010.

Comment: I took a quick look at my source archive; all Delphi versions ship with newer WSDLImp sources than each previous Delphi version, but I'm not sure they are the actual sources used to build Delphi with.

Comment: After a few weeks with this, I have made so many changes, that I decided to create a separate exe, and restore the original so that I can use mine for this specific project. I've now implemented my own setters, getters and change tracking logic built right in. The Delphi WSDLImport project contains mostly constants with placeholders. The only problem I have with running a slightly older version of the source, is that I had to change ansistring to string. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Since I'm a curious type: Would you care to share the source changes you made?